# What are some real life applications of limits?

Tags: limits

I have been recently taught limits  in calculus but I don't see any real life applications. Are there any? Thanks.

Comment: Plenty in physics, I am sure.

Comment: Limits in calculus are supposed to give you a taste of what limits $are$, e.g. what happens when some $n >> N$ (asymptotically). Later in, e.g. Stochastic Calculus you will come across applications in finance that rely  heavily on various results involving limits.

Comment: Without limits you wouldn't have calculus, so no statistics, modern-day engineering, economics...

Comment: Limits are how you make "infinitesimal" rigorous. Without it, it's very hard to define derivatives and integrals, which are the cornerstones of physics.

Comment: Limits allow you to define "instantaneous rate of change", one of the most fundamental concepts in physics and science.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Let $X$ denote a random variable that can take any positive integer value.

Given the probability function $P(X=k)=\frac{1}{2^k}$, find the expected value of $X$.

The solution is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2^k}\right)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

[Motion Paradoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Paradoxes_of_motion)

Actually this is one of the historical reason of the development of limits and calculus. Particularly, the solution to these kind of problems coincide with the birth of modern mathematics in the XVII century and the break with ancient mathematics.

Without calculus and limits, you cannot solve these paradox and prove, for example, that if you move from a poit A to a point B, you can reach the final point B.